# TFS2010 How can I update WorkItem Remaining/Completed Work for a previous date

Tags: tfs

After much searching on the web I can't seem to find this option.

If I forgot to update my Work Items Remaining/Completed Work how can I amend it for a previous date?

By forgetting; the Burndown chart looks wrong. Although I appreciate that I can update the values on a date following the date I forgot but this still makes the Burndown chart look funny and also means I can't record the work done retrospectively.

Could possibly the TFS Power Tools help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any powertool that does this, however the field for past revisions are read only when using the Client API, so it's very unlikely that a tool exists.

About your only option is to go straight to the database, probably the WorkItemsWere table, which isn't usually a fun experience.